# Is there a way to free memory from a activty when a new one is started?

Tags: android

I'm having some memory issues and trying to free up as much space as posable.
The activity that starts my project has a really big bitmap that can be scrolled back and forth.

Is there a way to free this bitmap when a new activity is started, and then re-load it when the activity is started again by the back button being pressed???

Comment: You can unbind the drawable in `onPause` and set the same in `onResume`. this will let gc free memory when it kicks in.

Comment: This is all done automatically unless you are doing something specific to hold onto the memory (like a static field for your bitmap). We would need to see code for more specific help. Most memory allocation is done automatically, google the Java Garbage Collector

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html. also check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the cleanup on `onPause()`, but that'd require to re-set the image back on `onResume()`.